# Resetting ArcGIS Pro Add in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, metadata, add-in

Recently I had ArcGIS Pro crashes because of an add in I installed. I followed the instructions for a clean uninstall of Pro and reinstalled it. But after re-install the add in still caused pro to crash.

Where does Pro keep the config settings for addins?

I was attempting to tweak some settings and now every time the add in is loaded pro will crash. I've downloaded a new add in file, I've removed and reinstalled the add in, and I've done a clean uninstall of pro but nothing works.

The add in:
https://github.com/USEPA/EPA-Metadata-Editor-Pro/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the location. It was in appdata/roaming/U.S. EPA.